# C++ understanding pointer with copy constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, deep-copy

I have a simple LinkedList class with basic operations(add/delete etc.) and a copy constructor:

```
LinkedList::LinkedList(const LinkedList& other) {
    data_ = other.data_;
    if (other.next_ == nullptr) next_ = nullptr;
    else next_ = new LinkedList(*other.next_);
}
```

I think the following behaviour is expected but I'm not sure why...

```
int main() {
    LinkedList list1;
    list1.insert(1);
    list1.insert(2);

    // prints 1->2
    list1.print();

    // Copy constructor called
    LinkedList list2(list1);

    list1.insert(3);
    // prints 1->2->3
    list1.print();

    // prints 1->2
    list2.print();

    // Memory addresses are different
    cout << &list1 << " " << &list2 << endl;

    delete &list1;
    
    // Nothing printed
    list2.print();

}
```

Should the reference to list2 also be deleted when list1 is deleted?

Comment: `delete &list1;` is illegal since you didn't (and shouldn't) `LinkedList* list1 = new LinkedList;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list1` was created in automatic storage ("the stack"), so you must not call `delete` on its address. Doing so results in Undefined Behaviour, which means that anything can happen, including corruption of `list2` or an outright crash of the program.

To test that your copy constructor is working, you could create both lists in dynamic storage ("the heap") using `new`, which must be paired with a matching `delete`:

```
int main() {
    LinkedList *list1 = new LinkedList();
    list1->insert(1);
    list1->insert(2);

    // prints 1->2
    list1->print();

    // Copy constructor called
    LinkedList *list2 = new LinkedList(*list1);

    list1->insert(3);
    // prints 1->2->3
    list1->print();

    // prints 1->2
    list2->print();

    // Memory addresses are different
    cout << list1 << " " << list2 << endl;

    delete list1;
    
    // Still prints 1->2
    list2->print();

    delete list2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and explanation!